# All forms shrinking in size after clicking a button

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I have searched everywhere and I really cannot explain it, I have made a project which starts with a login form at the size I have set, after I put login data and press the button next forms or even the login form shrinking in size as you can see from the image and I cannot understand if it is a bug or something else (I have tried everything about properties, autosize, windowstate etc but nothing).

```
private void btnLogIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        mycon.Open();

        //string cmdstr = "SELECT Password FROM admin WHERE ID ='" + textBox1.Text + "' ";
        string cmdstr = "SELECT Password FROM admin WHERE ID =" + textBox1.Text;

        cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmdstr, mycon);

        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        string[] login = new string[3];

        while (dr.Read())

        {

            login[1] = (dr["Password"].ToString());

        }

        dr.Close();

        mycon.Close();

        if (maskedTextBox1.Text == login[1])

        {

            MessageBox.Show("LOG-IN SUCCESSFUL!", "Confirmation Message");

            Form control = new Form2();

            control.Show();

            this.Hide();

        }

        else

        {

            MessageBox.Show("LOG-IN FAILED!", "Confirmation Message");

        }
    }
}
```

}

[image]

Comment: From the image you posted, the forms don't appear "minimized" as they are still visible on the screen (both the login form and your message box). I am assuming then there is some other form you are meaning that is displaying as minimized. Can you post the code from your login button? How are you displaying the next forms? As it stands now, your question is too broad to answer.

Comment: yes you right, maybe "getting minimized" isn't the correct term, they re just getting tiny as you can see from the image, all 5 forms of the projects, im adding the code.

Comment: Are you saying that the login form is actually shrinking in size after you click the login button? Your code is showing that you are hiding the form, so not sure why it would stay visible and shrink.  Or, are you saying that the login form is smaller than you expect when it is first displayed (and the same for all other forms)? What kind of font scaling to you have set on your system? Font scaling will affect how things are displayed. What zoom level do you have in your VS designer? If you have that zoomed in, then naturally the form will appear bigger in the designer.

Comment: When first displayed, login form is at the size i have set (the one you see from the designer at image) after i put login data and if they re correct the next form which is one form with 3 buttons will be at the same shrinking size and if i choose to press any of these 3 buttons the next forms will again have the same shrinking size, of course if the login data are false only the first login form will be shrunken. If i start a new project, no login form just one form with a button which opens a new second form everything will be fine and that's why the whole thing is really weird.

Comment: My screen resolution is 3840x2160 with 250% scale which are the recommended settings, i also tried to change resolution etc but the problem still remains.

Answer (score 0):

### Still happens today in Fall 2023, no to dpi scaling in App.Config seems to work

I have had this problem for several years in a little homemade tool for my own use and finally decided to work on it.
My form would open in the size it is designed,  but once I click a button it shrinks dramatically.

[This answer for a different scaling question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66160408/1518460) seemed worth a try and was the only thing that helped of the several I tried, including the others on that page.
To copy it here – fully thanks to that author and not me –

```
<System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationConfigurationSection>
    <add key="DpiAwareness" value="PerMonitorV2" />
    <add key="EnableWindowsFormsHighDpiAutoResizing" value="false" />
</System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationConfigurationSection>  
  
// again, this is by Umer Javaid who made this on the linked related question so go upvote that
```